# Is it possible to reuse types returned from web service to a type from a common DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, dll

My google-fu is not sufficient.

I have two web services that use a common DLL that holds structures for many of my commonly-used objects. In my client app, I implement both web services because the client app needs to do both things. In the client app, I also include the common DLL.

**WebServiceA**

```
[ServiceBehavior]
public class WebServiceA : MyServiceBase, IWebServiceA
{
    ...
    public GlobalDLL.AuthObject Authenticate(...)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**WebServiceB**

```
[ServiceBehavior]
public class WebServiceB : MyServiceBase, IWebServiceB
{
    ...
    public void DoSomeStuff(GlobalDLL.AuthObject auth)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My client app has two web service references and a reference to the GlobalDLL.

```
ServiceReferences
    WebServiceA
    WebServiceB
References
    GlobalDLL
```

When I created my web references in the client application, I made sure that "Reuse Types in referenced assemblies" was checked, and set to "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies." However, this doesn't seem to be working the way I expected it would.

When I call `WebServiceA.Authenticate(...)` within my client app, it returns a type of `WebServiceA.AuthObject`.

How do I convince my client application that the returned `WebServiceA.AuthObject` and the expected `WebServiceB.AuthObject` are really `GlobalDLL.AuthObject` so that I can pass it to `WebServiceB.DoSomeStuff(authObject)`?

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to work -- doesn't authentication include encryption that requires a certificate for that specific web service?   It seems to me that if your idea worked it would break existing authentication (or at least expose a man in the middle vulnerability)

Comment: These are two branches of the same system. I don't know why they split them into two different web services, but that is out of my control.

Comment: They're not the same type, so they can't be "reused".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the answer, and it was pathetically easy.
1) You MUST be using A WCF service. (I am.)
2) In the configuration, turn on "Re-use types for existing..." (I did.)

Here's where things went wrong for me. I had to remove the object that I wanted to reuse, and re-add it to the project. THEN, refresh the service references. When I did that, in that order, it linked up things the way it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same exact instance, but why not just create the correct instance for your services?  In other words,

```
WebServiceA.AuthObject authObjA = WebServiceA.Authenticate(...);
WebServiceB.AuthObject authObjB = new WebServiceB.AuthObject();
authObjB.prop = authObjA.prop;
```

etc?

You could create a method in your GlobalDLL to centralize the logic for "copying" these objects.